# ASP.net MVC Routes sub directory to root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following scenario:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{countrycode}/{languagecode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SignIn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, countrycode = "us", languagecode = "en" }
        );
```

Incoming requests have the url pattern:

`https://example.com/[countrycode]/[languagecode]`

Now I also want to support a sub directory that should act similar to when the root is requested, eg:

`https://example.com/subdir/[countrycode]/[languagecode]` -> should go to -> `https://example.com/[countrycode]/[languagecode]`

The same should work for controllers and actions requested via the sub directory, eg:
`https://example.com/subdir/[countrycode]/[languagecode]/signup/index` -> should go to -> `https://example.com/[countrycode]/[languagecode]/signup/index`

Is this possible via MVC routing, or should I use URL rewrite?